# how to get the code file of another aspx page attached to my aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My problem is to make a code behind file of an aspx i.e already existing 1.aspx pages aspx.cs 
to be available to another page aspx with out replicating any of the code in code behind.

i.e 1.aspx --> code file is 1.aspx.cs.

now 2.aspx --> code file is 1.aspx.cs

under the condition that the controls used in both aspx pages have identical Ids

Comment: This is an abuse of the DRY and KISS principles... I really hope you reconsider your design

Comment: You change the `<%@ Page CodeFile="page2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page2ClassNane" %>` and place code behind you like, but you going to face other problems and issues (probably including conflicts on dll compile) and is better to avoid it.

Comment: thank you guys..i will consider your and have took care all the conflicts and dependencies.
preferably i wouldn't do it but to avoid maintenance i have to do the above process thanks any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, if you have such requirement, you should better encapsulate common behavior either in a base class that can be inherited by the two page's dedicated class, or create utility/business class that contains the code.

You should also consider using User Controls. This can help you to create reusable visual component in your application.